# Apply external custom binding to included schema

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jaxb2

I am using binding.xjb to apply custom binding to main.xsd. Works fine.

I want to break down main.xsd to include say "common.xsd" but doing that breaks my binding.xjb.

example: below is my binding.xjb (one of the bidnings)

```
<jaxb:bindings node="/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType[@name='Job']/xsd:attribute[@name='stagingId']">
  <jaxb:property generateIsSetMethod="true"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

How should I change this binding if I have to move the element "Job" to common.xsd ?

I have tried below which din't work

```
// Because noew "common.xsd" will have its own "xsd:schema" element 
node="/xsd:schema/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType[@name='Job']/xsd:attribute[@name='stagingId']"

node="//xsd:complexType[@name='Job']/xsd:attribute[@name='stagingId']"
```

As I understand - the trick is to write appropriate XPATH to reach that node.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Karephul

**UPDATE: I found out that these custom bindings can be moved inline to where element is defined.**

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage episode files for this.  Episode files allow you to reuse the artifacts generated from one XML schema when you generate classes from another XML schema that imports the one you previously generated classes from.

Below is an example of how you produce an episode file.

```
xjc -b binding1.xml -episode common.episode common.xsd
```

And below is an example of how you consume and episode file.

```
xjc -d out main.xsd -extension -b common.episode
```

**Full Example**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/reusing-generated-jaxb-classes.html

Comment: I am using maven and I see that its being declared as <schemaIncludes>                           <schemaInclude>llc/api/message/main.xsd</schemaInclude>
                              </schemaIncludes>
                             <bindingIncludes>
                                 <bindingInclude>mhs/api/message/binding.xjb</bindingInclude>
                             </bindingIncludes>

Comment: So, really best way to do is write proper XPATH instead of messing with the build system.